# Is there a more eloquent word for a zigzag?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

The title pretty much says it all. Is there a more eloquent word for a zigzag?

**Edit:**

Allow me to clarify, I'm referring to the shape of a zigzag, a picture is attached below.
[image]

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment. As @Malvolio says, it's a *sawtooth* pattern (as opposed to a "sinewave", which would not have the sharp angles).

Comment: @Fumble You are confused, now you say it *is* a wave, but if that is so, it is most definitely *not* a sawtooth.

Comment: @z7sg: I said it's a pattern, not a wave. I mentioned *sinewave* purely to make the point about shap angles. Besides, even if I'd said *sinusoidal* the same would apply. Luckily OP isn't asking for the name of a strip pattern like that, with significant width. Nor is he asking about names for graph shapes, IMHO.

Comment: That's called "pinking" - you do it with **"pinking shears"**.  7sg below got the right answer first.

Comment: I assume we're not discussing "rolling papers" here...

Comment: The pictures resemble rickrack (fabric trim in a zigzag pattern).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These objects resemble a *triangle wave* (not a sawtooth as others have suggested).

[image]

The other thing it reminds me of is *pinking*, although that usually describes a zig-zag edge on a piece of fabric.  This material has been *pinked*:

[image]

Comment: Just because it's not a *sawtooth wave* doesn't mean it's not a *sawtooth pattern*.

Comment: You'll note that OP's pictures show quite substantial *width* to the lines. A *triangle wave* is a mathematical entity with no real concept of 'line width', so I'm afraid I still have to stick with *sawtooth*, which doesn't have to imply anything to do with graphing functions.

Comment: @phenry *Sawtooth* in the dictionary: "shaped like the teeth of a saw with alternate steep and gentle slopes" does not describe the object.

Comment: Saw teeth may be cut with no *rake*, especially when the saw cuts bidirectionally -- this is particularly true of two-man saws designed to cut seasoned (as opposed to green) wood across the grain, and of veneer saws. *Pinking* refers specifically to the treatment of a fabric edge to prevent or delay fraying, so while the shape is right, the word would be wrong for more general application.

Comment: @Stan I mentioned the usual meaning of *pinking* as an edging cut applied to fabric, however, it is not solely used on fabric.  You can also *pink* paper.  Saw blades have teeth, though the word *sawtooth* describes a certain shape, rather than meaning 'any shape that may be found on the blade of a saw'.

Comment: @Stan, everything zsg just said in that comment, is correct!  :)

Answer (score 9):

*In what way is "zig-zag" not eloquent enough for your purposes? (I'd argue that a single word can't be eloquent or non-eloquent, but that's a different subject.)*

The most technical term for the zig-zag pattern in your pictures is *[triangle waveform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave)*. This is probably too technical for most purposes, though.

Informally at least, *[sawtooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave)* can be used as a loose synonym, but that word actually refers to a different shape — right triangles instead of isosceles triangles: 
[image: sawtooth]

In heraldry, a zigzag edge treatment is called *[indented](http://www.heraldsnet.org/saitou/parker/Jpglossi.htm#338)* and/or *[dancetty](http://www.heraldsnet.org/saitou/parker/Jpglossd.htm#194)*.

A more general term is [*jagged*](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=jagged), but that carries connotations of unevenness.

There's also [*pinked*](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=pinked), from [*pinking shears*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinking_shears). This only applies to a zigzag treatment of a single edge, though, not the strips in your pictures.

Comment: +1 for dancetty (being a geek I picture this as using a remote terminal while listening to a bit of techno :-)

Answer (score 5):

If it's very regular, it's a *sawtooth*.  If it's wavy and intended as an obstacle course, it's a *slalom*.  What's your context?

Comment: I think *sawtooth* is a good alternative.

Comment: I'd say sawtooth tends to refer to a pattern with sharp drops -- though in common speech I don't think it'd matter mcuh. In wave terms the picutre is more of a *triangle* wave.

Answer (score 5):

For the metal inlay strips in your example photograph, *zigzag* is probably the best word. If there were many identical strips inlayed in parallel (and "in phase", so to speak) you might get away with calling the overall effect a *herringbone*, but that word is best applied to a 90° zigzag created by butting rectangular shapes (as below):

[image]

or a similar pattern woven into cloth (as opposed to printed). It would be the resemblance to a *herringbone tweed* that makes the term appropriate for parallel inlays.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant word I can think of is "alternate." But "sawtooth" and "jag" appear correct, if less elegant.